# Python Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out why there is difference in Total when the sum() on a DF called on single line and the same logic is split into different lines.

subset of columns taken to a list and this list is then passed to sum()

```
hd_list=df.columns
d_list.to_list()[4:10] 

####['col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8','col9']

df['Total']=df[hd_list].sum(axis=1)
```

The total expected for the first record is 45+49+49+65+65+45 =318 but received 320.0

But, if the same code is written in a single line (without an intermediate list) as below , it is returning the expected 318

```
df['Total']=df[df.columns.to_list()[4:10]].sum(axis=1)
```

Please help me to understand the difference between these two methods .Thanks for  the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first call

```
hd_list=df.columns
l=d_list.to_list()[4:10] 
df['Total']=df[l].sum(axis=1) # here you need slice the list after [4:10]
```